# fpdf displays a box after every line

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am working on fpdf to create pdf

I am using the following code :

```
$pdf = new tFPDF();
$questions = $_POST['question'];
$count = count($questions);
$quests = "";
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu','',14);

$pdf->SetTextColor(50,60,100);

$pdf->AddPage('P');


$pdf->SetFontSize(12);

for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
{
    $qus_id = $questions[$i-1];
    $get_q = "select * from `SelleXam_question` where `id`='$qus_id'";
    $get_q =  $wpdb->get_results($get_q);
    $questf = "Quest $i : ".$get_q[0]->question;
            $pdf->Cell(0, 10, iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $questf)."\n");                                if($get_q[0]->image !=='')      {           $pdf->Ln();         $path = plugins_url();          $imagenurl = $path.'/roque/uploads/'.$get_q[0]->image;                      $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $pdf->Image($imagenurl,$pdf->GetX()+60, $pdf->GetY() + 5,50,50), 0, 0, 'L','');       }
    $questf = "Option 1 : ".$get_q[0]->op1;
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $questf."\n");
    $questf = "Option 2 : ".$get_q[0]->op2;
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $questf."\n");
    $questf = "Option 3 : ".$get_q[0]->op3;
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $questf."\n");
    $questf = "Option 4 : ".$get_q[0]->op4;
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $questf."\n");
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->Ln();
}
```

The pdf is created but when I display the pdf then a small box is created at the end of the line, example of pdf is :

http://www.provarapida.net.br/wp-content/plugins/roque/pdfs/03102015121244_q.pdf

How can I remove these boxes ???

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "\n" at the end of your strings. A Cell() does not support several lines and tFPDF seems to subset the character incorrectly or to a missing glyph character.